# HighCharts- How to display dash style between low and high in column range type series and display value in it

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular8

I need to generate a report using high chart for column range,  where i need to display a divider between low and high value and also display value next to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsvjark/2/

```
series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            low: 7,
            high: 8
        },{
            x: 0,
            low: 8.1,
            high: 9,
            color: "#202020"
        },{
            x: 1,
            low: 6.5,
            high: 7.5
        },{ 
            x: 1,
            low: 7.5,
            high: 8.5,
            color: "#202020"
        }]
    }]
```

is it possible to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A lot of customizations are possible with Highcharts. The achieve the wanted result, you can for example use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class and add custom line shapes and text. For example:

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container1',
  type: 'columnrange',
  inverted: true,
  events: {
    render: function() {
      const chart = this;

      this.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
        const {
          x,
          y,
          height,
          width
        } = point.shapeArgs;

        const xPos = y + height / 2 + chart.plotLeft;
        const yPos1 = x + chart.plotTop;
        const yPos2 = x + chart.plotTop + width;
        const text = point.low + (point.high - point.low);
        const margin = 4;

        if (!point.customLine) {
          point.customLine = chart.renderer.path().attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: point.color,
            zIndex: 3
          }).add();

          ...
        }

        point.customLine.attr({
          d: [
            'M', xPos, yPos1 - margin,
            'L', xPos, yPos2 + margin
          ]
        });
        ...
      });
    }
  }
}
```

You can also consider using [annotations](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module) or [flag series](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/flag-series)

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zn14y7fp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer